# Terminate Observable chain when one of them errors

Tags: android, rx-java, reactivex

I have a chain of Rx Completables that I want to run one after another. I am using `concat()` to do this since I do not want them all to start at the same time.

```
view.welcome_message_edittext.verifyNotEmpty(getString(R.string.enter_your_email_address))
    .concatWith(view.welcome_message_edittext.verifyEmailAddress())
    .concatWith(sendMessageToBot())
    .subscribe({
        // The user has successfully entered data into the edittext, entered an email into the edittext, and sent message to bot. 
    }, { error -> })
```

The code above is saying this, "Assert the user has entered text into the EditText. If that is true, assert the user has entered an email into the EditText. If both of those are true, send a message to the bot." If the user enters text into the EditText but it is not an email, I expect the chain of Completables to break and onError() gets called.

[image]

This is what I want to happen ^^^. When *any* of the Completables calls `onError()` (as `verifyNotEmpty()` and `verifyEmailAddress()` do if user leaves EditText empty or does not enter email address) then I expect the entire chain to terminate and call the `.subscribe()` `onError()` function.

But, looking at the docs for `.concat()` this is the actual behavior of it:

[image]

`concat()` will simply move onto the next Completable when `onError` is called. The chain continues.

So my question is, what do I need to use in order to break the chain when any of the Completables call `onError()`?

Comment: I don't see any error event in the last screenshot. An error event is marked with a cross on a time line. So it should be ok to use concat in that case

Comment: @Buckstabue I am using `concat()`. The code snippet above is my actual code snippet in my app. When I run the code, leave the EditText blank, the `verifyEmailAddress()` and `sendMessageToBot()` functions are both called afterwards. The `subscribe()`'s `onError()` is called, but I expect the chain to terminate and `verifyEmailAddress()` is not called after `verifyNotEmpty()` calls `onError()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to collect all errors? If so, look at mergeDelayError( ) operator

Comment: @Buckstabue From the code snippet in my question, I have 3 Completables chained together. `verifyNotEmpty()`, `verifyEmailAddress()`, and `sendMessageToBot()`. The behavior now: if the EditText that `verifyNotEmpty()` runs on is empty, the `subscribe()`'s `onError()` is called and then the Completable chain *continues* by calling `verifyEmailAddress()` and `sendMessageToBot()`. I want:  if the EditText that `verifyNotEmpty()` runs on is empty, the `subscribe()`'s `onError()` is called and then the Completable chain terminates and does not call `verifyEmailAddress()` and `sendMessageToBot()`.

Comment: well, but that's not the actual behavior, if you concat Completable and got error, it will be terminated and not continue, why do you think that it's continue? Observable contract guarantees that terminal event (onError()) will end the chain.

Comment: Let me guess. It's absolutely normal that the method  verifyEmailAddress() is called and I suspect you are doing some business logic right there outside of an observable. You can put that logic inside the observable and it will be calculated lazily
It's similar to difference between Observable.just(getMyInteger()) and Observable.fromCallable(() -> getMyInteger()). In the second case getMyInteger() will be lazily called after subscribing while the first one is called immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Buckstabue in the comments for helping me debug this issue. His comment:

> Let me guess. It's absolutely normal that the method verifyEmailAddress() is called and I suspect you are doing some business logic right there outside of an observable. You can put that logic inside the observable and it will be calculated lazily It's similar to difference between Observable.just(getMyInteger()) and Observable.fromCallable(() -> getMyInteger()). In the second case getMyInteger() will be lazily called after subscribing while the first one is called immediately

Went back to my code and viewed my `verifyEmailAddress()` and `sendMessageToBot()` functions:

```
private fun sendMessageToBot(): Completable {
    insertChatMessageIntoConversation(ChatMessage(view!!. welcome_message_edittext.text.toString()))
    return Completable.complete()
}

fun EditText.verifyEmailAddress(): Completable {
    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(text.trim()).matches()) {
        return Completable.error(RuntimeException("Enter a valid email"))
    } else {
        return Completable.complete()
    }
}
```

The logic of the functions were not *inside* of a Completable block. I did not think that this mattered when I wrote the code because I thought that Rx's behavior was that it executed each Completable and waited for them to complete or error completely before moving onto the next Completeable. Therefore, skipping the `sendMessageToBot()` and `verifyEmailAddress()` functions entirely. Not the case.

This works:

```
fun EditText.verifyEmailAddress(): Completable {
    return Completable.fromCallable({
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(text.trim()).matches()) {
            val errorMessage = context.getString(R.string.enter_email_address)
            error = errorMessage
            throw RuntimeException(errorMessage)
        }
    })
}

private fun sendMessageToBot(): Completable {
    return Completable.fromCallable {
        insertChatMessageIntoConversation(sage(view!!. welcome_message_edittext.text.toString()))
    }
}
```